# How to get correct value of custom attribute of any tag in IOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

**Situation :**

Getting wrong data by clicking on hyperlink in UIWebview. so want to know the correct code and need help to correct where i made mistake.

**Expected Result :** To Get the data_cascade_uid of selected hyperlink in web view which is the custom attribute of  tag

**Example :** I written below html block of code to show contents into UIWebview

**Block of HTML Code**

```
<p>Code OB is <a data-cascade-uid="98170f1e-d213-4dbf-a1a6-6d6fcc5142ba" href="">coming soon</a>; If there is an Obstetrical <a data-cascade-uid="376f52bf-789c-4cea-b0d8-f2cffef1e4a2" href="">Emergency</a> please call Women&#39;s and Babies Dept..at SCS.</p>
```

Trying to accessing the url in this way using web view delegate method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked){

        NSURL *url = request.URL;
        //if valid url then move to browser 
        if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"https"] || [request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"http"]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
            return NO;
        }
        else
        {
             // getting Wrong data like this applewebdata://D0D0AF87-4369-4E26-9AD2-6971A37FD571.
        }
        return YES;

    }
    return YES;
}
```

In this code, there are 2 hyperlink in code. So I want to get associated data_cascade_uid of clickable link when user clicked on any of the link into web view. but i am getting wrong data while i clicking on any of link into webview.

Can anyone help me to written code or provide me code snippet how can I do this in iOS?

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to all link clicks and fire a custom navigation request which you listen for in the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method you implemented. Note that you first need to register a URL Scheme in your app (e.g. `myurlscheme`) which is pretty straightforward and done in the Info tab of your project in Xcode.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName != 'a' && e.target.tagName != 'A') {
        return
  }
    window.location = 'myurlscheme://somehost?data=' + e.target.getAttribute("data-cascade-uid")
}, false)
```

Comment: You can remove the white space and inject this piece of code as a string into the web view in the “did load” event. The method used to inject this into the web view is called `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`, or something similar.

Comment: NSString *datas = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {if (e.target.tagName != 'a' && e.target.tagName != 'A') {return} window.location = 'atlas://somehost?data=' + e.target.getAttribute('data-cascade-uid')}, false)\n</script>\n<div id=\"removeall\">\n%@</div>\n</body>\n</html>", finalHTML];

Comment: i tried this and load htmlstring into webview its returning me applewebdata://something... in webview shouldStartLoadWithRequest() method

Comment: can u please pass me code snippets how can i resolved this?

Comment: i want to get that <a> tag attribute value in native code of iOS

Comment: Your string `NSString *datas` looks good, change your `else` to an `if else ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"myurlscheme"] { // get query param called data here }`. Also, make sure you register the URL scheme `myurlscheme`.